# Meteor user account email verification

Tags: meteor

I am trying to set up email verification for users. I am using `useraccounts:core`'s `enforceEmailVerification` and i have the following on my server

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  var userId = user._id;
  Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId);

  if(options.profile.invite){
    Invites.remove({_id: options.profile.invite});
  }

  user.profile = options.profile

  return user;
});
```

When I try to sign up as a user i get the following server error

```
I20150206-18:12:08.648(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'ATCreateUserServer' Error: Can't find user
I20150206-18:12:08.648(-5)?     at Object.Accounts.sendVerificationEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:562:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.648(-5)?     at Meteor.methods.deleteAccount.userId (app/server/accountsMeld.js:12:12)
I20150206-18:12:08.648(-5)?     at Object.Accounts.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1024:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:693:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at Object.Accounts.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:751:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.ATCreateUserServer (packages/useraccounts:core/lib/methods.js:66:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:182:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599:1)
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150206-18:12:08.649(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem also and according to this: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/35#issuecomment-40674250 ,

it's not a good idea to put `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId);` inside `Accounts.onCreateUser` because the user doesn't yet "exist".

If you're using a method you can return the userID when the user is created, then  send the email afterwards, like so:

```
var userID = Accounts.createUser(options, callback);
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userID);
```

Comment: Alas, I get an error with this as well because createuser doesn't have a callback yet.

Comment: @corvid The callback is a function you define yourself, though you don't have to have one there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put sendVerificationEmail inside Accounts.createUser and set the timeout

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

 // we wait for Meteor to create the user before sending an email
 Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id);
 }, 2 * 1000);

 return user; 
});
```